Help with derivation of dirac delta from divergent integral
I'm following this paper, and I'm having a problem in the normalization of the continuous eigenfunctions (eqs. (67)-(70)), which satisfy
\begin{equation}
 \langle f_s|f_{s'}\rangle = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2 \, du}{(1-u)^2} f_s(u)^*\, f_{s'}(u) \,.
\end{equation}
The singular contribution of the integral arises at the endpoint $u=1$ of the integral, and in the limit $u \to 1$, the function $f_s(u)$ takes on the form
\begin{equation}
 f_s(u) \approx a_s (1-u)^{1/2 + is} + a_{s}^* (1-u)^{1/2-is}
\end{equation}
$f_{s'}(u)$ is also given by this expression but with $s \to s'$, where $s,s' \in \mathbb{R}_0^+$ and where $a_s,a_{s'} \in \mathbb{C}$ are complex coefficients in terms of $s, s'$, respectively.
Using these approximations, they immediately present in equation (70) the normalization condition
\begin{equation}
 \langle f_s | f_{s'} \rangle = 4 \pi |a_s|^2 \delta(s-s')
\end{equation}
which is what I'm trying to obtain. My attempt at solving this involved splitting the integral into two, as follows
\begin{equation}
 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2 \, du}{(1-u)^2} f_s(u)^*\, f_{s'}(u) = \int_{0}^{1-e^{-1/\varepsilon}} \frac{2 \, du}{(1-u)^2} f_s(u)^*\, f_{s'}(u) + \int_{1-e^{-1/\varepsilon}}^{1} \frac{2 \, du}{(1-u)^2} f_s(u)^*\, f_{s'}(u)
\end{equation}
and solving for the latter, which contains the divergent part. I used the $u \to 1$ approximation presented above and simplified the expression to a sum of $4$ terms. Each term is an integral of the form (singular endpoint - problem arises here)
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{I} = \int_{1-e^{-1/\varepsilon}}^{1} (1-u)^{i(s+s')-1} \, du = -\frac{i e^{-\frac{i(s+s')}{\varepsilon}}}{s+s'}
\end{equation}
After integrating all terms and using using dirac delta identities involving trigonometric functions, I got
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I} = -4 \pi |a_s|^2 \delta(s-s')
\end{equation}
I believe the problem comes from the way I solved the $\mathcal{I}$ integral, which leads to a sign discrepancy between what I obtained and the paper.

It's unclear as to the meaning of the parameters $s$ and $s'$ in the asymptotic expression "$f_s(u) \approx a_s (1-u)^{1/2 + is} + a_{s'}^* (1-u)^{1/2+is'}$."  What is the analogous expression for $f_{s'}(u)$?

@MarkViola Thank you for pointing that out, I had made a mistake in the approximation of $f_s(u)$ and I fixed it. Indeed for $f_s(u)$ only $s$ is present, whereas for $f_{s'}(u)$, there is $s'$ instead of $s$, where $s,s' \in \mathbb{R}_0^+$.

Hi, sorry for the delayed reply. If I understood your question correctly, the parameters $s, s'$ are positive real numbers and the dirac delta is defined in the usual sense $\delta(x-x_0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i p(x-x_0)}, dp$.

And please feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)

There is ambiguity in the definitions of terms within the posted question.  The following presentation is, therefore, not intended to be a full answer.  Rather, it is intended to provide a possible way forward. To that end, we now proceed.

Let $g_s(u)$ and $g_{s'}(u)$ be defined as
$$\begin{align}
g_s(u)&=a_s (1-u)^{1/2 + is} + a_{s}^* (1-u)^{1/2-is}\\\\
g_{s'}(u)&=a_{s'} (1-u)^{1/2 + is'} + a_{s'}^* (1-u)^{1/2-is'}
\end{align}$$
where we will proceed by assuming that $s$ and $s'$ are positive real numbers. Then, proceeding formally, we have
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^1 \frac{2\left(g_{s}(u)\right)g_{s'}(u)}{(1-u)^2}\,du&=2\int_0^{1} \frac{a_sa_{s'}u^{i(s+s')}+a_sa_{s'}^*u^{i(s-s')}+a_s^*a_{s'}u^{-i(s-s')}+a_s^*a_{s'}^* u^{-i(s+s')}}{u}\,du\\\\
&=2\int_{0}^\infty \left(a_sa_{s'}e^{i(s+s')u}+a_sa_{s'}^*e^{i(s-s')u}+a_s^*a_{s'}e^{-i(s-s')u}+a_s^*a_{s'}^* e^{-i(s+s')u}\right)\,du
\end{align}$$
Of course this last expression diverges if it is interpreted as a Lebesgue or Riemann integral.  However, we can interpret the last expression as the sum of Fourier transforms of the Heaviside function $H(u)$.  Then, we can write
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^1 \frac{2\left(g_{s}(u)\right)^*g_{s'}(u)}{(1-u)^2}\,du&=2a_sa_{s'}\left(\pi \delta(s+s')+\text{PV}\left(\frac{i}{s+s'}\right)\right)\\\\
&+2a_sa_{s'}^*\left(\pi \delta(s-s')+\text{PV}\left(\frac{i}{s-s'}\right)\right)\\\\
&+2a_s^*a_{s'}\left(\pi \delta(s-s')-\text{PV}\left(\frac{i}{s-s'}\right)\right)\\\\
&+2a_s^*a_{s'}^*\left(\pi \delta(s+s')-\text{PV}\left(\frac{i}{s+s'}\right)\right)\\\\
&=4\pi |a_s|^2 \delta(s-s')+4\text{Im}\left(a_sa_{s'}\right)\text{PV}\left(\frac{i}{s+s'}\right)+4\text{Im}\left(a_sa_{s'}^*\right)\text{PV}\left(\frac{i}{s-s'}\right)
\end{align}$$
where the Dirac Delta $\delta(s+s')$ is the zero distribution since we assumed that $s>0$ and $s'>0$.

Thank you for the answer. Proceeding in this way does yield the expected result of $ 4\pi |a_s|^2 \delta(s-s') + \text{other terms}$. The problem lies now with the other terms which supposedly shouldn't exist.

You're welcome.  My pleasure.  What do we know about $a_s$?
